# can I post data to my server directly instead of firebase

Tags: firebase

I am considering firebase for an app - mainly for the real-time but other features like the analytics and authentication (and price) are other bonuses.

I have my own database and I want everything saved in there. Firebase will have a small portion of the dataset I push as it's needed.

So I'm basically thinking that the firebase data will be read only to the users.  If a user comments, that will actually go to my server, I'll authenticate, clean, whatever.. and push to the that feed.

Are there problems with this approach?  Are there other (better) ways to solve the problem?

Comment: Sounds good to me. It's actually a quite common pattern. For auto-scaling of the server-side code I'd consider using Cloud Functions, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a completely valid approach. Firebase is designed so you can use specific features that suit your needs.